How do I pass a hidden text field as well as changle the form action
I have a script that will take a page name and change the form action, which will then take me to that page. However, I also want the ID for the page content to be passed to it. I assumed that a hidden field would work. I get the page, but there is no content.
<script language="javascript">
<!-- Script courtesy of http://www.web-source.net - Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development
function goto(form) { var index=form.select.selectedIndex
if (form.select.options[index].value != "0") {
location=form.select.options[index].value;}}
//-->
</script>
<form name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
<select name="select" onchange="goto(this.form)">
<option value="">-------Choose a Selection-------
<option value="view.php">View
<option value="download.php">Download
</select>
</form>

I then capture the ID on the receiving page with.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // collect value of input field
    $app_id = $_POST['id'];
}


I don't understand your form as you haven't told it the method is post so it'll go as a get. What debugging have you done in the PHP - have you checked whether the post method is indeed being used? As far as I can tell from what you have shown us, it isn't.

what does "changle" mean? is it change? I don't want to assume

You need to put method="POST" as an attribute of the form, or else it will send a GET request and therefore the $_POST array in php won't be populated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#the_method_attribute

P.S. location=form.select.options[index].value;} in the script will cause the page to navigate to another URL using the location command. This does not "change the form action" and it does not submit the form. Therefore none of the form's values will be appended to that new navigation request. So that's part of your problem, too.

You can do this to change the form method based on a condition in PHP. About the hidden field, your solution implementation looks reasonable (provided I don't have more details on what you are trying to do).
<?php

$yourcondition = false;

$formMethod = $yourcondition ? 'post' : 'get';
// Placeholder echo so you can verify your condition actually works.
echo($formMethod)
?>

<form action="your_action.php" method="<?php echo $formMethod; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="exampleField" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The default form is a GET request.
So you only need to add method="POST"
<form name="form1" method="POST">

Or when receiving data in PHP, change it to:
$app_id = $_GET['id'];

